# Sails 404 when loading view

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-generate-auth

I'm usings Sails, and I've just installed the sails-generate-auth package and created an api.

In my routes.js I have:

```
   'get /register': 'AuthController.register',
```

and within my AuthController I have:

```
  register: function (req, res) {
    res.view({
      errors: req.flash('error'),
    });
  }
```

I then have an ejs file called register which is located in

```
views/auth/register.ejs
```

For some reason, when I go to /register, I get a 404 message.  I've turned on silly logging but it doesn't tell me much:

```
verbose: Sending 404 ("Not Found") response
silly: View override argument passed to res.view():  404
silly: Serving view at rel path:  404
silly: View root:  /Users/Greg/Documents/Projects/photorank-web/views
```

I've tried to manually specifiy the view file to load, but this doesn't seem to work either.  Has anyone got any pointers as to what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you finished [this tutorial](https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth)?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure it's even a package problem.  I'm just using sails as normal but it cannot detect the view

Answer (score 1):

How do you *manually specify the view file to load*?

It should look like this in the *AuthController*:

```
register: function (req, res) {
  res.view(
    'auth/register',
    { errors: req.flash('error') }
  );
}
```